# Will all applications work fine on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit

I used Ubuntu some time ago and now I want to switch on it again since community raised a lot and so did support for applications like Wine. I remember that when 64bit version just came out many applications didn't work as they did on 32bit version. Is it not better or still the same? Maybe they implemented something like [WoW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) in Windows that simulates 32bit architecture and every possible app is working just fine. I am asking because I have lots of ram and I don't want to sit on 3GB when I have 8.

Also, I am somewhat of a programmer, but that is not a problem because if I write PHP I use NetBeans on Windows anyway, and it works on Linux just as fine. But I also love to write C++/C# code. Is it well supported? I really like Visual Studio 2010, it is very slick and has good auto completion, debugging and so on... Is there any IDE on Ubuntu that is similar to Visual Studio in terms of auto-completion, code formatting, GUI designer, debugging?

I really hope you will answer me these questions because I really like to "convert" myself to Ubuntu once and for all.

Comment: Consider breaking your questions into separate inquiries.

Comment: For C# on Ubuntu, I'd definitely take a look at MonoDevelop: http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Kory is right, the second paragraph should be a completely separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Most applications work just fine in a 64-bit OS. I haven't actually run across any that don't, but as soon as I say all applications one is bound to pop up.

As to your 8GB RAM point. Unless you have processes that take more than 4GB of RAM then a 32-bit OS with the PAE kernel will address all 8GB of your RAM.

Comment: Pretty much anything in the Ubuntu Software Center should be fine, but I got so sick of fighting with 64-bit Flash and Java, that I eventually moved back to 32-bit.

Comment: 64-bit Flash and 64-bit Java work for me

Comment: Also install ia32-libs.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the 64-bit Ubuntu version is concerned, I have had zero difficulties running either native Linux applications and/or Windows programs under Wine.  Obviously there is software out there, with which I have no experience, but I would suggest that the 64-bit Ubuntu version is much better than it was a few years ago when I was trying to get it up and functioning properly on a past laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I installed 64-bit Ubuntu just a few weeks ago and the only problem I've encountered so far is that LinkSys AE1000 wireless adapter doesn't work with it: the drivers provided by Ralink are only 32-bit and I couldn't get them to work with 64-bit Ubuntu.  Everything else, though, has worked as well, if not better, than before.  I'm very glad I made the switch, since the 64-but OS seems to be a little faster overall (more than I expected, frankly).

But I'm not a programmer: your mileage may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 64 bit Linux: in many respects, linux has better 64 bit support than windows in that there are more key applications that are 64 bit native.  Ubuntu has improved very much in the past few years with regard to 64 bit support; flash is now available in "preview" mode for native 64 bit support.  Also, the 32-bit support w/in 64 bit generally works as a fallback.

Regarding an IDE, I would recommend Eclipse, if you're looking for an all-language, integrated IDE.  It has the richest plugin ecosystem (moreso than VS).  But, being a guy who considers it "forced" to have to use VS2010, I personally like gedit.  Good old gedit has syntax highlighting for most languages (and community available packages for more), and very many plugins to do code completion, bracket completion, etc...  It's lightweight and easy to use.  http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins